# Loading a custom data type from a text file Haskell

Tags: file, parsing, haskell, types, readfile

I have a custom data type, `Person`.

```
data Person = Person{ fname :: String
                    , lname :: String
                    , age :: Int
                    , siblings :: [String]
                    } deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Read)
```

I also have a text file which has data formatted like

```
"bob" "ross" 60 ["sam", "ron"]
"fname" "lname" age ["sibling1", "sibling2"]
"fname" "lname" age ["sibling1", "sibling2"]
```

I want to load each line from the text file into my custom data type, `Person`. Since there are multiple lines it'll be `[Person]`.

```
contents <- readFile "persons.txt"
let database :: [Person]
    database = read contents
```

So `database` should be of type `[Person]` and each element in `database` relates to a line from `persons.txt`.

I have a function which converts `[Person]` to a string, but when I try

```
putStrLn (personsToString(database))
```

I get `*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse`

Thank you.

Comment: Well those strings aren't valid `Person` values since they lack the constructor.  Prefix them with the `Person` constructor then try `Read` or read each field and manually construct the `Person` value for each line.  Also consider using `readMaybe` so you can give prettier error messages when parsing fails.

Comment: The contents of the file should look more or less like the string you get doing `show (listOfPersons :: [Person])` if you want `read` to parse it

Comment: The discussion so far ignores the fact that Read is not a good parser in general. This applies even more to the derived instance. The real solution here is to use one of the many parser combinators library. See Parsec for example.